# Does deleting the table users prevent all logins?

Tags: admin, login, security

I uploaded a Wordpress site online but it is taking time to configure the server.  In the meantime I deleted the table "users" so hackers cant access the site/backend, until I can secure the site properly at a future date.  Will this work or can the site still be hacked through site.com/wp-login?

Comment: That's not a good idea, how would functions such as `get_user_meta()` work if there is no user table in your database?

Comment: I am not using meta data.  But I will put the table back in when the server is setup. The question is not about having the site work smoothly but is it more secure, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question yes without the user table no one will be able to login because the database holds no login information.

you may of been better off securing your /wp-login from brute fore attacks in a different way https://wordpress.org/support/article/brute-force-attacks/

i.e limiting the ip access to the login area

Comment: why would limiting IPs be better?  That way it is possible  that the login is hacked.  If no one can login at all then it cannot be hacked, according to your answer.  I do not understand what you are trying to say.  With 1 click I prevented all logins?  Or I did not and I should configure the server that I am trying to configure?

Comment: securing your admin area is standard practice and something you may want to do and have in place for when your site is live so my point was yes what you have done is going to stop any logins but at some point you will have to login so how much server work is needed to protect your install, you may as well just followed standard practice because at some point you will have to do my suggestion anyway.

Comment: So your answer is yes.  The bulk of your answer does not answer the question, and cannot be implemented for specific reasons.  It can be confusing if you add spurious information to answers.

Comment: you dont go into the specific reasons so question can not be answered in full

Comment: the question is - does removing users stop logins.  You said yes.  Why is that not fully answering the question?

Comment: @Jon you cannot give such as small answers here, so we wanted to elaborate a bit more, if that small answer satisfied you, don't bother reading more and be happy, let Brad be!

Comment: @Castiblanco The continuation of the answer does not answer the question, is misleading at best and wrong at worst.  why can you not give a shorter answer?  If you don't like my comments - dont read them.  let me be!

Comment: hahaha feels good, right?